Quantifying the Discrepancy Between Two Distributions with Sensitivity to Outliers
I have two probability distributions over a sample space $x \in \Omega$, denoted by $P: \Omega \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ and $Q: \Omega \mapsto \mathbb{R}$. These distributions arise in the context of constructing decoders for error-correcting codes. Suppose $\Omega$ represents the space of all possible errors, and $P(\cdot)$ is an error model that assigns a probability to each error event in $\Omega$. In essence, $P(\cdot)$ captures all the undesired effects. If a decoding strategy has complete knowledge of $P(\cdot)$, it can perform optimally. However, $P(\cdot)$ is generally unknown in practice. Instead, we often perform calibration experiments to infer a model $Q(\cdot)$ that reasonably approximates the underlying noise process $P(\cdot)$. Therefore, it is crucial to understand how $P(\cdot)$ and $Q(\cdot)$ differ, particularly in terms of the performance of a decoder.
In error correction, it is well known that errors $x \in \Omega$ that lie in the tail of $P(\cdot)$, i.e., outliers, critically impact the performance of the decoder. For instance, if $\Omega$ represents independent bit-flip errors, where each bit-flip occurs with probability $p$, critical outliers are errors with large Hamming weights (just over half the code's distance $d$), with probabilities around $p^{d/2}$. Therefore, it's crucial for $P(\cdot)$ and $Q(\cdot)$ to closely match on the outliers, while larger discrepancies are more acceptable for non-outlier errors.
In this context, what would be a suitable distinguishability metric to quantify the relevant differences between $P(\cdot)$ and $Q(\cdot)$? The following commonly used metrics seem unsuitable for this particular case:

Total Variation Distance (TVD): $\sup_{x \in \Omega} |P(x) - Q(x)|$. This metric is dominated by differences in probabilities of the more likely events. For example, if we have two errors $x_1, x_2 \in \Omega$ with $P(x_1) = 0.9$, $Q(x_1) = 0.8$, and $P(x_2) = 10^{-5}$, $Q(x_2) = 10^{-7}$, the TVD is insensitive to the significant error in estimating the probability of $x_2$.
Kullback-Leibler Divergence (KL Divergence): $ D(P || Q) = \sum_{x \in \Omega} P(x) \log \left( \frac{P(x)}{Q(x)} \right) $. Like TVD, the KL divergence is more sensitive to discrepancies in $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ for typical events. It thus does not sufficiently capture differences in the outliers.

